# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kendoAutoComplete is not a function

Tags: kendo-ui

I encountered this error when I use Kendo UI to develop my project.

[image]

this is my html code:
[image]

[image]

Comment: You could delete this post because it isn't very useful for other developers imo

Answer (score 1):

resolved. The reason is that it overlaps with other js files

Comment: Removing the overlapping js files solved the problem for me as well. Thanks!